# Using chrome.browsingData.remove() in incognito mode

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have an extension removing the downloads made in Google Chrome using this line of code in my background page:

```
chrome.browsingData.remove({ "since": 0 }, { "downloads": true });
```

When a download is in a normal window it works however when a download has been made in an incognito Chrome window it is not removed. My extension is activated in incognito mode and the background page is able to detect when a download in the incognito page has been completed using:

```
chrome.downloads.onChanged.addListener(function(download) {
    if (download.state && download.state.current == "complete") {
        // The code here is fired even if the download has been completed in incognito mode
    }
}
```

Is there a way to remove the browsing data in incognito windows from a background page?

Comment: This may be to do with whether you're using [`spanning` or `split` incognito mode](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/incognito) for your extension. I'd imagine if you were using `spanning` mode, a download received in incognito mode would fire the event, but the call to clear the downloads fires in the main chrome profile - they're separate APIs after all. Try `split` mode if you haven't already!

Comment: Also try using [`chrome.downloads.erase`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#method-erase) instead. Only having a dependency on a single API means less to change when something gets deprecated!

Comment: @JimO'Brien You can transform your first comment in an answer, it is the perfect solution and explanation for this problem!

Comment: Consider it done - the upvote/accept will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you're facing is that your extension is running in [`spanning` incognito mode](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/incognito). This means that the extension runs under a single process attached to the profile that installed the extension (i.e. not the incognito window). In this situation, the `chrome.downloads` API fires the `onChanged` event for downloads in both incognito and normal profiles, but the `chrome.browsingData` API only applies to the normal profile.

Instead, you want to use `split` incognito mode. This means that the extension runs separately in each profile that uses it (i.e. the incognito window gets its own running copy of the extension). This means that when you call the `chrome.browsingData` API, it applies to the window that fired the event.